# Python lib: undefined symbol: _Py_FalseStruct

Tags: python, linux, installation, pip, debian

I tried to install pybgpstream without sudo rights on a machine.
Python installation is system wide. I had to install everything under ~/.local/lib... 
After installing libbgstream binary I wanted to install pybgpstream with

```
pip install --global-option build_ext --global-option '--include-dir=/home/USER/.local/include' --global-option '--library-dir=/home/USER/.local/lib' pybgpstream
```

After successfull installation I tried running some script with pybgpstream. Doesn't work:

```
ImportError: /home/USER/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pybgpstream.so: undefined symbol: _Py_FalseStruct
```

I added /home/USER/.local/lib/ to LD_PATH...
I don't know what's wrong...

Comment: It looks like you compiled the lib with python 3, but are trying to run it with python 2.

Answer (score 0):

There's a docker solution to work with pybgpstream. Here is the docker file

```
FROM python:3.8
 
RUN apt update \
&& apt install -y build-essential curl zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev librdkafka-dev python3-gi-cairo nano \
&& mkdir ~/src && cd ~/src/ && \
curl -LO https://research.wand.net.nz/software/wandio/wandio-4.2.3.tar.gz && \
tar zxf wandio-4.2.3.tar.gz && \
cd wandio-4.2.3/ && ./configure && make install && ldconfig && \
cd ~/src/ && \
curl -LO https://github.com/CAIDA/libbgpstream/releases/download/v2.1.0/libbgpstream-2.1.0.tar.gz && \
tar zxf libbgpstream-2.1.0.tar.gz && \
cd libbgpstream-2.1.0/ && ./configure && make check install && ldconfig && \
pip install pybgpstream && \
pip install ipython && \
pip install statsmodels && \
pip install matplotlib && \
pip install ipykernel && \
pip install pylint && \
pip install autopep8
 
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

You can also use this container every time and run bgp streams